# AndEngine: how to attach a child twice

Tags: android, andengine

I create a text, register a MoveXModifier (i.e. modA) to the text, and attach the text to a scene, it works well.

Then I bind a listener to the modifier, and what I do in the `onFinish()` method of the listener is:

1. set the text invisible;
2. do some calculation;
3. detach the text from the scene;
4. clear modifiers of the text;
5. create a new MoveXModifier(i.e. modB) and register it to the original text, set the text visible;
6. attach it to the scene again.

The first modifier(modA) works well, but the second modifier (modB) didn't functions as I assume, the text just stay there, seems that I can't attach the same text twice.

(PS: I set the text invisible to ensure that the text is brought by modB again rather than by modA just once).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `newModifier=oldModifierObj.deepCopy();`.

Then register the new one. `registerEntityModifier(newModifier);`

Comment: I do create a new modifier and register it, though the new modifier is not created by deep copy. Seems that's not the point.

Answer (score 0):

A child can only have one parent, if you want to use single sprite twice on different occasions you can detach it first then attach it to a new parent.
if you want to use two at the same time you must have two objects.

Comment: Thanks for telling me the correct usage of text object, but my case is to detach it first and attach it to the old parent, is that possible? I tried but the new modifier is not functioning well(see the updated steps of 3.4.5.6. above)

Comment: make sure that you are resetting the modifiers before using them again